# AndroidNetworking.post() method giving error response

Tags: android

I am using AndroidNetworking `OkHttp` client to store my registration details in DB, But it's giving some error response.

please help me, first time I am dealing with service calls..here is my code

```
       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
               .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
               .build();

       AndroidNetworking.initialize(Registerpage.this,client);


            AndroidNetworking.post("http://localhost:8090/api/user/create")
                    .addJSONObjectBody(jsonObject) // posting json
                    .setTag("test")
                    .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                    .build()
                    .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            // do anything with response


                                }
                           @Override
                        public void onError(ANError anError) {
                            Log.w("JSONRESPONSE","GOT JSON ERROR");
                            anError.printStackTrace();
                        }
                            }
```

Error Response is:

> com.androidnetworking.error.ANError: java.io.IOException: unexpected
>   end of stream on okhttp3.Address@....6865

Comment: try to replace "localhost" with your "IpAddress".

Comment: again it's giving same response ..@MiteshVanaliya

Comment: Is there a connection? Look in your server logs.

Comment: Try the same url in a browser on your device.

Comment: when i try the same url in my system browser its giving "This page can’t be displayed" result

Comment: there is a connection to DB i'm able to store the data into my DB from postman by using the same url in the form of Json..@greenapps